# Draft js performance issue when applying inline style to large selection

Tags: performance, reactjs, draftjs

I am using Facebook's Draft.js library to create a inline text editor! Draft js has been exceptionally good so far but I am facing a performance bottlenect now! I have a color picker in my inline editor which allows the user to add text color to the selected content! It works fine when the selection is a small text but if the user's selection spans multiple lines, draft significantly slows down! One can even replicate this issue in [React WYSIWYG](https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/) example and the react's own [color](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/color/color.html) example! I am not sure whether this is a known issue or I have missed somthing, any advice on this is much appreciated!

Comment: that is true, because `draftjs` manage a list of style for every character.

Comment: Any possible update regarding this? I know that it's an old post, but I face the exact same problems for textes which can be as long as books chapters.